# Google drive app not working in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-drive

Just upgraded to OSX Yosemite. And the google drive app seemed not to be working. Anyone else experienced the same issue? It seemed to be able to sync the documents in my folder in OSX and the folder in drive.google.com even though the app is inaccessible.

[image]

I tried to re-install it by downloading the google drive app and replacing it. But I was prompted that I could not replace it since it was running. I searched in terminal with command: `ps aux | grep 'google drive'` located it and killed it by `kill 477` and then I was able to re-install it. But still it's not working since it's still grayed out like the attached picture above.

It's not working like; I could not open the application. I was not able to access the application to click around on settings to; sign in or sign off or sync. It's grayed out and when I click on it it's not working it's not responding. I tried to right click and do something but still it is not responding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this workaround/fix](http://ralfrottmann.net/fix-google-drive-mac-app-on-yosemite):

> - Open Terminal.
> - Paste the following command:
>
>   ```
>   sudo cp /Applications/Google\ Drive.app/Contents/Resources/Google\ Drive\ Icon\ Helper /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/
>   ```
> - Enter your password.
> - Either restart your machine or use Activity Monitor to force quit Google Drive and restart the application.

Comment: Nice! THis works now. Could you explain a bit more what exactly this command does?

Comment: I think path is changed. try:
sudo cp  /Applications/Google\ Drive.app/Contents/Helpers/Google\ Drive\ Icon\ Helper  /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did...

Delete the Drive settings directory `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Drive`

I found the answer here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/scZdhCkzN1w

Comment: Did that force you re-download all of your files?

Comment: Looks like is checking files for changes and not re-downloading anything, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I'm glad you figured it out as I added this answer last year so couldn't remember. Cheers for updating to let us all know. :)

Comment: You can also rename the folder if you're unsure. This has worked well for me and Google Drive didn't have to re-download all the files.